# Calculate database size in Oracle Essbase

Tags: olap, olap-cube, essbase

Classical question at tests:
I have 4 dimensions:
Markets: Sparse, 10 stored members, 10 total members
Products: Sparse, 5 stored members, 7 total members
Accounts: Dense , 10 stored members, 11 total members
Time : Dense, 5 stored, 12 total

What is the size of that BSO? How do I calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Essbase [Database Administrators Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/esb_dbag/frameset.htm?launch.html) has a worksheet you can use to calculate the size of a cube.

For your example, you have 2 dense dimensions:

- Accounts - 10 stored members
- Time - 5 stored members

Total number of cells in a block: 50.

8 bytes per cell, so 50 * 8 = 400 bytes expanded block size.

You have 2 sparse dimensions:

- Markets - 10 stored members
- Products - 5 stored members

So you have 10 * 5 = 50 possible data blocks, for a total (assuming the database is entirely filled) of 20,000 bytes.